# How come PySpark can't find my SPARK_HOME

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a Jupyter notebook from Archives Unleashed locally on my machine. When the notebooks builds PySpark, it runs into this exception:

`Exception: Unable to find py4j, your SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly`

Any idea on how I can configure the SPARK_HOME?

I have tried to run the notebook in a clean conda environment. This is the full notebook until the error:

```
%%capture

!wget "https://github.com/archivesunleashed/aut/releases/download/aut-0.50.0/aut-0.50.0.zip"
!wget "https://github.com/archivesunleashed/aut/releases/download/aut-0.50.0/aut-0.50.0-fatjar.jar"

!ls

%%capture

!apt-get update
!apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq 
!apt-get install maven -qq

!curl -L "https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.4.5/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz" > spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!tar -xvf spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz
!pip install -q findspark

import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7"
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars aut-0.50.0-fatjar.jar --py-files aut-0.50.0.zip pyspark-shell'

import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

This is what I get returned:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/miniconda3/envs/arc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/findspark.py in init(spark_home, python_path, edit_rc, edit_profile)
    142     try:
--> 143         py4j = glob(os.path.join(spark_python, "lib", "py4j-*.zip"))[0]
    144     except IndexError:

IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-03823ebc9ad8> in <module>
      1 import findspark
----> 2 findspark.init()
      3 import pyspark
      4 sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
      5 from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/arc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/findspark.py in init(spark_home, python_path, edit_rc, edit_profile)
    143         py4j = glob(os.path.join(spark_python, "lib", "py4j-*.zip"))[0]
    144     except IndexError:
--> 145         raise Exception(
    146             "Unable to find py4j, your SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly"
    147         )

Exception: Unable to find py4j, your SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"/content/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7"` is not the correct `SPARK_HOME`. In the `curl -L` line, you downloaded Spark to somewhere, and then you extracted it. Find where it's downloaded and extracted to, and set `SPARK_HOME` to that path.